# GetDirectories, problem with space in the path

Tags: c#, .net, networking, directory

i have a problem with the access to a network path with spaces in the directory.
The path is something like '\server\dir1\file to read'.
When i try to read it, an exception throw.(can't find the path)

This is the code i tried:

```
string startPath = @"\\server\dir1\dir to access\";
String[] p = Directory.GetDirectories(startPath)
```

If i try to remove the spaces all work fine.
What i wrong?

ok, i solved...due my error, i saw the directory as mapped but was not share on network...so the path was wrong

Comment: Could you please specify what kind of exception is thrown (error message)? Also you cannot get subdirectories of a file (Your path ends with "File to read").

Comment: it's really unclear if there is a directory called `"file to read"`...

Comment: i assumed there was when i read the question

Comment: Obviously the path without the spaces exists and there is no folder with spaces in its name located at given path. Are you sure the name of the folder is "dir to access" and not "dirtoaccess"?

Comment: The spaces in the path should not be a problem. Please specify exception and its message. 
Also `Directory.GetDirectories` returns `string[]` not `string`

Comment: the exception is "System.IO.IOException" (impossible find the path)